# how to replace user's names with random names?

Tags: mysql, random

How can I use SQL only on mysql DB to replace first and last names of real users in **users** table using a random name from two related tables: **random_first_names** and **random_last_names**. Our users table contains over 250K records and each of the rundome tables contain over 5000 names that should be picked at random for each record in **users** table. Is it possible to achieve with SQL only?

**[UPDATE]**

I solved the problem based on Rick's input and shared the full SQL script below.

Comment: do you want something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260307/anonymizing-customer-data-for-development-or-testing ?

Comment: Thank you @moudiz . It looks similar but I'm not sure it answered my question, which is how do I for each record in **users*** table update _users.name_ with random result from **names** table?

Comment: I suggest you put the answer part in a proper answer.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you decide that the Update is too slow, I suggest the following will be about 1000 times as fast.

Loop (can be done in a Stored Proc)...

1. [Re]Create a table with randomly ordered set first_names, with a `PRIMARY KEY of 1..5000.  Ditto for last_names (a second table).
2. Multi-table `UPDATE` the 'next' 5000 rows joined to the two random tables.  Use `ON Users.id % 5000 = RandomFirstNames.id` (etc)

End Loop

Shuffling the table (step 1 of the loop) is something like

```
CREATE TABLE RandomFirstNames (
    id SMALLINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(...),
    PRIMARY KEY(id) )
SELECT first_name FROM FirstNames ORDER BY RAND();
```

**After OP's UPDATE**

Don't do

```
SELECT count(id) INTO count_names FROM _RandomFirstNames;
```

Instead, do this once:

```
SELECT @mask_ct := COUNT(*) FROM _masked_names;
```

and use `@mask_ct` instead of `count_names`;

As for the skipped ids, `CREATE TABLE _RandomFirstNames` without an id, then `ALTER TABLE _RandomFirstNames ADD id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;` to get the ids.  This should give you ids without gaps (unless you are on a multi-Master cluster of any kind).

Comment: Thank you Rick, I was not sure how to make this work, but it gave me a direction to do additional research. I've updated my original question with an improved script, but it still has an issue.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your issues.

Comment: Thank you Rick. Adding ID after the operation, did the job! Could you please clarify the benefit of using  SELECT @mask_ct := COUNT(*) FROM _masked_names; instead of my current solution? In my solution I could number of records of in the names table and go through the loop until it exceed users' count. I'm not sure why I'll need to get count from _masked_names which never changes.

Comment: @user1525248 - Your solution involve counting the _resulting_ table _every_ time through the loop.  My version involved a single count before starting the loop.  (The difference between `@variables` and Declared variables is not significant.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ORDER BY rand()` in combination with `LIMIT 1` to select a random row of your random names tables.

```
UPDATE users
       SET first_name = (SELECT name
                                FROM random_first_names
                                ORDER BY rand()
                                LIMIT 1),
           last_name = (SELECT name
                               FROM random_last_names
                               ORDER BY rand()
                               LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: This should work... eventually.  It will take about 2.5 _billion_ operations.

Comment: Thank you Sticky Bit, while your solution does the job from functional perspective, this option is not practical as it runs extremely slow. I terminated the script after waiting for 10 min running on a test set of 250,000 users.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Rick and Sticky Bit for you inputs. Sticky Bit's solution would take to long to run. Rick's answer was the closest one and his comments helped me to create the full solution which I'm sharing below.

First, create temporary tables to store random names

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _RandomFirstNames;
CREATE TABLE _RandomFirstNames (first_name VARCHAR(255));

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _RandomLastNames;
CREATE TABLE _RandomLastNames (last_name VARCHAR(255));
```

Then created a procedure to fill those tables with random names to make sure that we have one first name and one last name per each possible user ID.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS prepare_randon_names$$
CREATE PROCEDURE prepare_randon_names()
BEGIN
        SELECT @users := id FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1;

        SELECT @mask_ct := COUNT(*) FROM _masked_names._firstnames;
        SELECT @loops := @users/@mask_ct;
        SELECT @count := 0;
        WHILE @count  < @loops DO
                INSERT INTO _RandomFirstNames (first_name)
                SELECT firstname FROM _masked_names._firstnames ORDER BY RAND();

                SELECT @count := @count+1;
        END WHILE;

        SELECT @mask_ct := COUNT(*) FROM _masked_names._lastnames;
        SELECT @loops := @users/@mask_ct;
        SELECT @count := 0;
        WHILE @count  < @loops DO
                INSERT INTO _RandomLastNames (last_name)
                SELECT lastname FROM _masked_names._lastnames ORDER BY RAND();

                SELECT @count := @count+1;
        END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

We can now execute it and add incremental IDs to the populated tables

```
CALL prepare_randon_names();

ALTER TABLE _RandomFirstNames ADD id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE _RandomLastNames ADD id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Now we can update user table with the random names by joining the two new tables with the random names that we created above

```
UPDATE users u
left join _RandomFirstNames f on f.id = u.id
left join _RandomLastNames l on l.id = u.id
       SET u.first_name = f.first_name,
           u.last_name = l.last_name;
```

And the last step, drop the tables with random names as we no longer need those

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _RandomFirstNames;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _RandomLastNames;
```

**Notes Summary**

- adding primary key after the tables were populated with random names solved an issue with the index skipping count. For example, in _RandomFirstNames, the ID was increased sequentially until ID 5163 and then skiped to 8192 (by 3,029), then it increased sequentially until 13354 and then skiped again by 3,029 to 16383. _RandomFirstNames was generated based on _masked_names._firstnames, which contained 5163 names.
- avoiding count(...) within the while loop increased speed by one second when run against `users` table with 250,000 records